# Is there a specific pattern for tracking Header Referrer Data in IHP apps?

Tags: ihp

Anyone have a recommendation/pattern for tracking HTTP: Referrer header data in an IHP app? I was thinking it might be best to add it to the `beforeAction` in the `Static` `Controller` for the app landing page but it could just as well go in the `initContext` in `FrontController`?

I'm wondering if there is a strong technical argument for one over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track it across the full application, use `initContext` in `FrontController`. If you only want it for specific controllers, go with `beforeAction`.

From a technical standpoint there's no major difference between these two places.